# (File.Error) could not read file "": no such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, elixir, windows-subsystem-for-linux, elixir-mix

I'm trying to run an elixir project, but when i try to install the dependencies with `mix deps.get`, i get this error:

```
** (File.Error) could not read file "/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/project/config/dev\r.exs": no such file or directory
    (elixir 1.12.3) lib/file.ex:355: File.read!/1
    (elixir 1.12.3) lib/config.ex:243: Config.__import__!/1
    (mix 1.12.3) lib/mix/config.ex:161: anonymous fn/2 in Mix.Config.__import__!/2
    (elixir 1.12.3) lib/enum.ex:2385: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (mix 1.12.3) lib/mix/config.ex:160: Mix.Config.__import__!/2
    (stdlib 3.16.1) erl_eval.erl:685: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

Actually I have the `dev.exs` file in the config folder, but i don't understand what this "`\r`" at the end of the file name at the error means.

i'm working with windows subsystem for linux, to use `asdf` to manage versions, the current ones are these:

```
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.1.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

Elixir 1.12.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 24)
```

Hope somebody can help me with this situation.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `\r` is a carriage return. It looks like whatever is setting the `dev` value is also including a carriage return at the end. It could be because of your config, or it could be related to differences between Linux and Windows newline sequences. Also FWIW `Mix.Config` is deprecated, use [Config](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a stray carriage return somewhere. Possibly in a string.

For example, on OSX, in iex I can generate a string like this by hitting return before adding the closing quote:

```
iex(1)> string = "dev
"
"dev\n"
```

I suggest you check your config for incorrect quoting, probably near the code that loads the environment specific config file (Typically something like `import_config "#{config_env()}.exs"` in `config.exs`.